# App Icons and Images in Phone's Photo Gallery

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I noticed that my photo gallery had a bunch of icons and other graphics from my cordova app after installing it on my Android phone. I faced no such issue with iOS.

Is there any configuration that I'm missing which prevents this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this happens only during development builds. No issues on production builds